# Umbraco - moved server, database issues

Tags: sql-server, umbraco

I have moved an Umbraco site from an old server to a new one.

I have copied all the files exactly via FTP (and set the correct Umbraco permissions) and also restored the SQL backup.

I edited the web.config to use the new SQL details, and I am ble to get into the backend (all the previous data e.g users, pages etc seem to be there)

However, I am greeted with the following message:

> Running Umbraco on Live on
>   my_domain.preview.fastwebhosting.net.
>   Connected to DB my_db_name with 'my_db_user'
>   user.
>
> WARNING! It looks like you are on the LIVE server but are connected to
>   the UNKNOWN database. Please check web.config!

It appears that the previous database had a user, dbo. I cannot re-create this user on the new server (using the hosts web interface), I tried and it simply said it already existed :/

Also (it may be related to this issue) the frontend simply does not load. I see a hosts error page. The backend loads perfectly oddly enough.

Answer (score 1):

dbo is the default schema in SQL Server and is described as follows on Microsoft Technet:

> The dbo is a user that has implied permissions to perform all
>   activities in the database. Any member of the sysadmin fixed server
>   role who uses a database is mapped to the special user inside each
>   database called dbo. Also, any object created by any member of the
>   sysadmin fixed server role belongs to dbo automatically.
>
> For example, if user Andrew is a member of the sysadmin fixed server
>   role and creates a table T1, T1 belongs to dbo and is qualified as
>   dbo.T1, not as Andrew.T1. Conversely, if Andrew is not a member of the
>   sysadmin fixed server role but is a member only of the db_owner fixed
>   database role and creates a table T1, T1 belongs to Andrew and is
>   qualified as Andrew.T1. The table belongs to Andrew because he did not
>   qualify the table as dbo.T1.
>
> The dbo user cannot be deleted and is always present in every database. Only objects created by members of
>   the sysadmin fixed server role (or by the dbo user) belong to dbo.
>   Objects created by any other user who is not also a member of the
>   sysadmin fixed server role (including members of the db_owner fixed
>   database role):
>
> 1. Belong to the user creating the object, not dbo.
> 2. Are qualified with the name of the user who created the object.

You should be fine if all of your tables are owned by dbo however I suspect they are now owned by the user you are connecting to the database with. You can change ownership of such objects back to dbo to avoid problems and the following might help with that but please use at your own risk as I take no responsibility if it does not work for you!

```
if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[chObjOwner]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[chObjOwner]
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  OFF    SET ANSI_NULLS  ON 
GO

CREATE proc chObjOwner( @usrName varchar(20), @newUsrName varchar(50))
as
-- @usrName is the current user
-- @newUsrName is the new user

set nocount on
declare @uid int                   -- UID of the user
declare @objName varchar(50)       -- Object name owned by user
declare @currObjName varchar(50)   -- Checks for existing object owned by new user 
declare @outStr varchar(256)       -- SQL command with 'sp_changeobjectowner'
set @uid = user_id(@usrName)

declare chObjOwnerCur cursor static
for
select name from sysobjects where uid = @uid

open chObjOwnerCur
if @@cursor_rows = 0
begin
  print 'Error: No objects owned by ' + @usrName
  close chObjOwnerCur
  deallocate chObjOwnerCur
  return 1
end

fetch next from chObjOwnerCur into @objName

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @currObjName = @newUsrName + "." + @objName
  if (object_id(@currObjName) > 0)
    print 'WARNING *** ' + @currObjName + ' already exists ***'
  set @outStr = "sp_changeobjectowner '" + @usrName + "." + @objName + "','" + @newUsrName + "'"
  print @outStr
  print 'go'
  fetch next from chObjOwnerCur into @objName
end

close chObjOwnerCur
deallocate chObjOwnerCur
set nocount off
return 0


GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  OFF    SET ANSI_NULLS  ON 
GO
```

#### Example of Usage

To change all the objects owned by user test to dbo, run the following code:

```
exec chObjOwner 'test','dbo'
```

> The code finds all the objects that are owned by test and generates a
>   series of SQL statements by using the sp_changeobjectowner stored
>   procedure. You can then examine and run the statements in the SQL
>   Server Query Analyzer.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/275312

Comment: Hmm, this might be on the right track. I have some tables owned by "my_db_user" and the rest (most of the tables) owned by "dbo". The problem being, is the Umbraco web,.config needs a DB user account in it?

Comment: Are those Umbraco based tables or are they related to third party packages? Did you use the web installer to setup the remote site database or did you restore a database to the server?

Comment: First time, I installed Umbraco normally, and it made some tables under "my_db_user" (I think. it didn't create loads, just a few tables). Then I uploaded the files from the old site, but the versions where off, so I deleted everything and just uploaded the files form the backup. I know have a DB with a few tables under "my_db_user" and loads under "dbo" (cms content and some umbraco* tables)

Comment: Use the script above to create the queries required to change the objects back to dbo ownership.